# Apache Pig - Store/Flatten Bag so it can output as CSV

Tags: apache-pig

Not a great question title I admit.

Here's my problem, I have the following output from a query, where each row is like:

```
{(570349476329862),(570349476329862),(570349476329862)} {(66638102521614253348753),(66638102521614253348753),(66638102521614253348753)} 3
```

The schema of the above is:

```
{{(ID1:chararray)},{(ID2:chararray)},COUNT:long}
```

What I'm trying to do is generate output in a CSV format so that it can be easily ingested into a database, e.g. turn the above into:

570349476329862,66638102521614253348753,3

I think I want to flatten the bags but although this 'compiles' it doesn't run.

Any ideas welcome.

Thanks

Comment: You might check out DataFu's `FirstTupleFromBag()` http://datafu.incubator.apache.org/docs/datafu/1.1.0/datafu/pig/bags/FirstTupleFromBag.html

Comment: Is it always duplicated tuple in each bag? So is it true that you just want to pick up the first tuple from each of the two bags and extract the values from them?

Comment: If you have code that almost works, please show the code, and describe more accurately what happens when "it doesn't run".

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same data on the bag e.g. result of a group, you can do 2 things:

- Involve the given field in the grouping, than you won't need to deal with that

`...
B = FOREACH (GROUP A BY (COUNT, ID1, ID2)) 
GENERATE FLATTEN(group) AS (COUNT, ID1, ID2),
...`

- Or use an inbuilt function e.g. MAX

  `...

  B = FOREACH (GROUP A BY COUNT) GENERATE 
  FLATTEN(group) AS COUNT,
  MAX(A.ID1) AS ID1,
  MAX(A.ID2) AS ID1,
  ...`
  The benefit of this compare with the suggested datafu function, that you can do it with an inbuilt function.

I hope this helps